# f:param not appending to url when h:commandbutton is clicked

Tags: jsf, primefaces

View:

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="job" value="#{controller.jobs}">
       <p:column>
          <h:commandButton value="Start" action="#{controller.start(job)}">
             <f:param name="jobName" value="#{job.name}"/>
          </h:commandButton>
     </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Bean:

```
public String start(Job job){
    return "/viewDetails?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

I am using `@ViewScoped` for my backing bean controller.

My problem is when I click start button, it doesn't append the param jobName with value `#{job.name}` to my url. Is there any way I can make it append?

Answer (score 4):

It's because you didn't specify it in the redirect URL.

```
return "/viewDetails?faces-redirect=true";
```

If you specify it in the redirect URL, then it'll — obviously — appear in the URL.

```
String jobNameParam = URLEncoder.encode(job.getName(), "UTF-8"); // Or ISO-8859-1, depending on server config.
return "/viewDetails?jobName=" + jobNameParam + "&faces-redirect=true";
```

Comment: Thanks. Why is it that when i use `<h:link>`, i do not have to explicitly specify it in the redirect url?

Comment: Because it doesn't send a redirect. I think it's time to take a JSF pause and learn basic HTTP.